# what is the alternative browser for lynx?

Tags: netbeans, lynx

**I have a script including JavaScript,when i run that in terminal,it says**

```
 JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.

   You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the
   functionality of this website.
```

And it asks for authorization?

(but,when i run this script in netbeans(shift+f6)..it works fine).

I need to run in terminal only because i have to set cron.

**Is there any other way for this ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a text mode browser which supports javascript?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34687/is-there-a-text-mode-browser-which-supports-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install links elinks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install w3m
```

w3m doesn't use the same keyboard shortcuts as other command line browsers, so get ready to learn some new ones. You can do that by pressing `shift+h` while running w3m.