# How can I browse view missing manpages from the command line?

Tags: command-line, manpage

http://manpages.ubuntu.com is a great resource for viewing manpages not installed in the system. However, it uses some weird programming to redirect short URLs like `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ls.1` to `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/ls.1posix.html`, and it always picks the latest release. Otherwise, it works fine when using `lynx` with the full URL. It even looks like a normal manpage:

[image]

The redirection doesn't work in `lynx` (or `elinks` or `w3m`). Just to check, I tried on my Arch Linux `elinks`, which apparently does support JavaScript:

```
$ elinks -version
ELinks 0.13.GIT a3751107033599b835eaafa61177c8d4dda4b7ef-dirty
Built on Oct 31 2013 20:43:18

Features:
Standard, IPv6, gzip, bzip2, UTF-8, Periodic Saving, Viewer (Search
History, Timer, Marks), Cascading Style Sheets, Protocol
(Authentication, File, CGI, FTP, HTTP, URI rewrite, User protocols),
SSL (OpenSSL), MIME (Option system, Mailcap, Mimetypes files), LED
indicators, Bookmarks, Cookies, ECMAScript (SpiderMonkey), Form
History, Global History, Scripting (Lua, Spidermonkey ECMAScript), Goto
URL History
```

[`edbrowse`](http://edbrowse.org/) didn't redirect either. That's that for the suggestions from [Is there a text mode browser which supports javascript?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34687/is-there-a-text-mode-browser-which-supports-javascript)

Using the full URL would be workable *if* I knew the section, which is not always the case. Is there a program which can bring up the online manpage, preferably for the running Ubuntu version? In case of matches in multiple sections, it should behave like `man` does.

Comment: Try `dman` in the `bikeshed` package: for `ls` it doesn't do that redirection, didn't test for the behavior in case of multiple matches though.

Comment: @kos Yep, for matches in multiple sections, it opens each section's manpages (but doesn't distinguish between 1 and 1posix, for example). Hmm, thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into improving it.

Answer (score -1):

You can just give lynx the search url with the man page you want. In the search results use the lynx `l` command to list the returned links and choose the one you want. Eg for `ls.1`:

```
lynx 'http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?lr=lang_en&q=ls.1'
```

Comment: -1 that still leaves me the problem of selecting one of the manpages myself. If I wanted to do this, I could just use the search box in manpages.ubuntu.com directly in lynx, without bothering with a ridiculous url

Comment: You can take the [dman](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dman) command mentioned by kos, which can take a `--release trusty` option, and uses `wget` on all the possible sections, doing a `man` on any that work. Simply replace the `man` by `lynx` on the equivalent url.

Comment: I can do a lot of things, but if I wanted to do things manually, I could already search in lynx without doing anything you have suggested so far.